# bash input redirection breaks stdin

Tags: c, input, terminal, stdin

I have a program that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <errno.h>

int enable_keyboard() {
    struct termios new_term_attr;

    tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &new_term_attr);
    new_term_attr.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ICANON);
    new_term_attr.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    new_term_attr.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    return tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &new_term_attr);
}

int main() {
    errno = 0;
    unsigned char field[H][W];

    fill (field);
    char c = enable_keyboard();;
    while(1) {
        read(0, &c, 1);
        printf("%d ", c);
    }
}
```

It reads a single char from stdin and displays it infinitely(in order to check whether enable_keybord works fine).
The problem is that when I run this program with input redirection(line `./a.out < test.txt`) it breaks all the input and `errno` is set to be 25.

Also `tcsetattr` returns -201 when it should return 0 or -1.

I tried to clear `stdin` with `scanf` before `tcsetattr` and also disabling `tcsetattr` completely but it turns out input redirection hangs all the input completely.

Without input redirection everything works perfectly fine so I guess maybe bash does something with stdin so it freezes dead in program.

Any ideas how to fix the problem?

Comment: `fill()`, `H` and `W` are undefined here I assume they are irrelevant to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`errno` 25 = "Inappropriate ioctl for device"; you are performing terminal operations on a file.  You do not check the return from `tcgetattr()`.  On error, it sets `errno` and that is set to `ENOTTY` if the file descriptor does not represent a terminal.  So:

```
int enable_keyboard() 
{
    struct termios new_term_attr;
    int status = -1 ;

    if( tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &new_term_attr) == 0 )
    {
        new_term_attr.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ICANON);
        new_term_attr.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
        new_term_attr.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
        status = tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &new_term_attr);
    }

    return status ;
}
```

That will not solve your "hanging" issue however - as you mentioned, your program loops indefinitely - the while loop does not terminate on EOF.  The problem is that EOF is not explicitly indicated by `read()` - rather it returns zero - which for terminal input simply mean no characters. In that case:

```
char c = 0 ;
bool is_file = enable_keyboard() != 0 ;
bool terminate = false ;

while( !terminate ) 
{
    terminate = read(0, &c, 1) == 0 && is_file ;
    printf("%d ", c);
}
```

Putting that all together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int enable_keyboard() 
{
    struct termios new_term_attr;
    int status = -1 ;

    if( tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &new_term_attr) == 0 )
    {
        new_term_attr.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ICANON);
        new_term_attr.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
        new_term_attr.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
        status = tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &new_term_attr);
    }

    return status ;
}

int main() 
{
    errno = 0;

    char c = 0 ;
    bool is_file = enable_keyboard() != 0 ;
    bool terminate = false ;
    
    while( !terminate ) 
    {
        terminate = read(0, &c, 1) == 0 && is_file ;
        printf("%d ", c);
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Note: Runnable test at https://onlinegdb.com/Inqm6w52D